# Managing Heroku RAM for Unique Application

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, memory, ram

I have a Flask application that allows users to query a ~small database (2.4M rows) using SQL. It's similar to a HackerRank but more limited in scope. It's deployed on Heroku.

I've noticed during testing that I can predictably hit an R14 error (memory quota exceeded) or R15 (memory quota greatly exceeded) by running large queries. The queries that typically cause this are outside what a normal user might do, such as SELECT * FROM some_huge_table. That said, I am concerned that these errors will become a regular occurrence for even small queries when 5, 10, 100 users are querying at the same time.

I'm looking for some advice on how to manage memory quotas for this type of interactive site.  Here's what I've explored so far:

- Changing the # of gunicorn workers. This has had some effect but I still hit R14 and R15 errors consistently.
- Forced limits on user queries, based on either text or the EXPLAIN output. This does work to reduce memory usage, but I'm afraid it won't scale to even a very modest # of users.
- Moving to a higher Heroku tier. The plan I use currently provides ~512MB RAM. The largest plan is around 14GB. Again, this would help but won't even moderately scale, to say nothing of the associated costs.
- Reducing the size of the database significantly. I would like to avoid this if possible. Doing the napkin math on a table with 1.9M rows going to 10k or 50k, the application would have greatly reduced memory needs and will scale better, but will still have some moderate max usage limit.

As you can see, I'm a novice at best when it comes to memory management. I'm looking for some strategies/ideas on how to solve this general problem, and if it's the case that I need to either drastically cut the data size or throw tons of $ at this, that's OK too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Coming from my personal experience, I see two approaches:

#### 1. plan for it

Coming from your example, this means you try to calculate the maximum memory that the request would use, multiply it by the number of `gunicorn` workers, and use dynos big enough.

With a different example this could be valid, I don't think it is for you.

#### 2. reduce memory usage, solution 1

The fact that too much application memory is used makes me think that likely in your code you are loading the whole result-set into memory (probably even multiple times in multiple formats) before returning it to the client.

In the end, your application is only getting the data from the database and converting it to some output format (JSON/CSV?).

What you are probably searching for is **streaming responses**.

Your Flask-view will work on a record-by-record base. It will read a single record, convert it to your output format, and return a single record.

Both your database client library and Flask will support this (on most databases it is called **cursors / iterators**).

#### 2. reduce memory usage, solution 2

other services often go for simple **pagination** or **limiting resultsets** to manage server-side memory.

#### security sidenote

it sounds like the users can actually define the SQL statement in their API requests. This is a security and application risk. Apart from doing `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements, the user could create a SQL statement that will not only blow your application memory, but also break your database.

Comment: Great suggestions. I'll explore streaming responses and plan on limiting result sets regardless. There's no use case for users to ever need to return more than 50 or so rows. On the security note, I plan to grant users only the SELECT permission, to avoid SQL injection, but it sounds like they could do other damage as well. What's an example of a SQL statement that would break the database?

Comment: depending on the size of the memory of the DB, I could build a complex `SELECT` query, then request said query multiple times. Then other users won't get any data or errors.